# Don't Capture mouse when wxToggleButton is clicked

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a number of custom wxToggleButtons in a wxGridSizer.
I want to be able to hold leftmouse + move the mouse to quickly activate multiple buttons (similarly deactivate them when right-mouse is down).

I've experimented with different bindings on wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW, wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN etc... The underlying problem is that wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW (also wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW) is not triggered while the mouse is down, so I assume the first button has captured the mouse in some way. The obvious wxWindow::ReleaseMouse() is not the answer, some different mechanism is at work.

I also took a quick look at subclassing wxMouseEventsManager, but I couldn't get it to work with the plan of returning false in MouseDragBegin(). I'm not sure if that is the appropriate approach here.

How do I disable this mouse capturing behaviour in my subclass of wxToggleButton?

Comment: Would you please share the code you've already tried?

Comment: The most successful plan so far has been:
`    void OnMouseEnter(wxMouseEvent &e) {
        wxToggleButton *btn = static_cast<wxToggleButton *>(e.GetEventObject());
        if (wxGetMouseState().LeftIsDown())
            btn->SetValue(not btn->GetValue());
        e.Skip(); //allow default coloring of a focused button
    }
`
but the mouseState.LeftIsDown() is never true.

Comment: I can confirm that `wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW` is not triggered in all circumstances. In Windows 10 and wx3.1 if I start `press-left-mouse-button + drag` from an empty place in the frame then it works. But if I start the action inside a wxTextCtrl then the mouse event handler is not called.

Comment: @user9808715: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50774415/edit) your question and write that source code into the question's body, instead of posting source code as a comment. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The reason I did not edit my question is because I believe it is sufficient as is, I'm asking for the right (or any functional) approach, not code. The line I commented doesn't even come close due to the problem with the mouse being captured. There is nothing available to a wxToggleButton (through inheritance or otherwise) that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I find out that is not wxWidgets, but Windows to blame.

Using Spy++ and the character map app, I pressed left mouse button in the small 'Unicode' text control. Then dragged it while keeping pressed the mouse button.

The 'Select' button did not receive any message at all.

Thus, in some cases a window blocks all messages for the other windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the mouse over a native button, it captures the mouse and only releases it when you release the mouse button. It is possible to forcibly break the capture but it's really not a great idea and would result in awkward and unusual UI because, whether you realize it or not, users are accustomed to the native button behaviour.

Comment: "It is possible to focribly break the capture". Why would you say this without even hinting as to how ?! Besides even if this behavior is indeed undesirable in 99% of cases, I feel this is an unbelievably lazy answer.

Comment: Breaking the capture is obviously done by calling Win32 `ReleaseCapture()` function but, again, this is a bad idea even under MSW and is not portable at all. Don't do this.

Comment: I'm coding this for linux/mac so no ReleaseCapture(). More importantly, while I appreciate the repeated warnings, I have 169 buttons in a grid that represent a continuous range, and the ability to quickly select/deselect large parts of it is critical, so I am convinced that this is the desired behavior. I'm going to take a closer look at wxMouseEventsManager, since that seems to be the only untested path left.

Comment: You didn't say that you were targeting Linux/Mac and the other answer mentioned Windows, so I assumed this is what you used. Anyhow, if you want to use non-standard UI, don't use standard controls. E.g. you could use `wxGrid` with button-like cell-renderers and then you'd be able to select many cells conveniently.